# Error using SharePoint REST API endpoint for creating a Modern Teams site: The parameter request does not exist in method CreateGroupEx

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to use the SharePoint REST API endpoint `_api/GroupSiteManager/CreateGroupEx` to create a SharePoint Modern Teams site

```
url: /_api/GroupSiteManager/CreateGroupEx
accept: application/json;odata.metadata=none
odata-version: 4.0
method: POST
body:
{
  "request": {
    "Title": "Communication Site 1",
    "Url":"https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/commsite1",
    "Lcid": 1033,
    "ShareByEmailEnabled":false,
    "Classification":"Low Business Impact",
    "Description":"MyDescription",
    "WebTemplate":"STS#3",
    "SiteDesignId":"6142d2a0-63a5-4ba0-aede-d9fefca2c767",
    "Owner":"owner@yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com"
  }
}
```

I have proven my API process by creating a Modern Communication site with the endpoint `/_api/SPSiteManager/create` and `"WebTemplate":"SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0"`

When I attempt to create the Modern Teams site I get the error:

`Failed: {"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The parameter request does not exist in method CreateGroupEx."}}}`

Answer (score 1):

Try to update the request body like below:

```
body:{
    "request": {
        alias: "Communication Site 1",
        displayName: "Communication Site 1",
        isPublic: true,
        optionalParams: {
            Classification: "Low Business Impact",
            CreationOptions: [`SPSiteLanguage:1033`,`implicit_formula_292aa8a00786498a87a5ca52d9f4214a_6142d2a0-63a5-4ba0-aede-d9fefca2c767`],
            Description: "MyDescription",
            Owners: "owner@yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Also I have noticed that changing the Accept to below helps:

```
'Accept': 'application/json;odata.metadata=minimal'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to work either. Irritatingly it states ```The parameter request does not exist in method CreateGroupEx``` but does not state which paramter is causing the issue.

Comment: Additionally I cannot find ANY documentation on the ```CreateGroupEx``` endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

It clearly complains about the "request" parameter, telling that there is no such parameter. Worked for me:

```
url: /_api/GroupSiteManager/CreateGroupEx
accept: application/json
method: POST
body: {
 "alias": "CommunicationSite1",
 "displayName": "Communication Site 1",
 "isPublic": true,
 "optionalParams": {
   "CreationOptions": [
    "SPSiteLanguage:1033",
    "implicit_formula_292aa8a00786498a87a5ca52d9f4214a_6142d2a0-63a5-4ba0-aede-d9fefca2c767"
   ],
   "Description": "MyDescription",
   "Owners": ["owner@yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com"]
 }
}
```

Some notes:

- alias should not contain spaces (it is a part of url and email nickname)
- I have no idea what the classification could be, just omited (your string does not seem work)
- owners should be an array, not a string

Comment: Looks like we are on the right track with this however it results in an ````Failed: {"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"A node of type 'StartArray' was read from the JSON reader when trying to read a value of a property; however, a 'PrimitiveValue' or 'StartObject' node was expected."}}}```` error, despite validating as JSON

Comment: I have checked the JSON - ````{"alias":"CommunicationSite1","displayName":"CommunicationSite1","isPublic":true,"optionalParams":{"CreationOptions":["SPSiteLanguage:1033","implicit_formula_292aa8a00786498a87a5ca52d9f4214a_6142d2a0-63a5-4ba0-aede-d9fefca2c767"],"Description":"MyDescription","Owners":["Mydomain.co.uk"]}}````

Comment: Hmm. I've tried the above JSON literally in postman, and it actually created the site for me. May be different server configuration? There are just two arrays, I'd try "Owner" as a plain email then, like in your original post maybe? For me, it was throwing an opposite exception, like "array is expected, but string found". Like, multiple owners not allowed?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. If I swap the arrays out I get the opposite ````Node type```` message.

Comment: Hi Nikolay, I have tried this in Postman myself now and cannot get a success. I always get the JSON node type message mentioned above. I know it is a pain but can you go through what settings you have in Postman so that I can try to get to the bottom of this please?

Comment: I executed the above query from my answer in POSTMAN (replaced "Site1" with "Site3") and I did not get any error, the site was successfully created. Screenshot: https://i.paste.pics/0d44cb39902331b554e7d0c51696d23a.png I did it also previously for Site1 and Site2, and also the queries succeeded. If this results in an error for you, this must be some configuration issue or version probably (I was using SharePoint online, i.e. site is on my-site-name.sharepoint.com)

Comment: There are no other settings I've changed in POSTMAN, I have only entered this text on the BODY tab, and then added the authorization. Did you try to copy-paste the request from the answer, 1-to-1? Could it be a language/locale thing? Can you create this site manually, using the user interface?